# Python - read a text file with multiple lines into a list

Tags: python, list, readfile

I would like to turn this (in a .txt file):

```
7316717653
1330624919
```

into this (in a Python list):

```
a_list = [7, 3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6, 2, 4, 9, 1, 9]
```

how do I do this? I've been looking everywhere, but nothing came close to what I intended to do

Comment: You can use this snippet  list(text.replace('\n',''))

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: @Xnkr ah, sorry about that, because I keep getting the wrong answer, I just delete all of the codes I've tried

Comment: You should read python.org tutorial first. You will get the answer yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lst = []
with open('New Text Document.txt', 'r') as f: #open the file 
    lines = f.readlines() # combine lines of file in a list
    for item in lines: # iterate through items of  lines
        # iterate through items in each line and remove extra space after last item in the line using strip method
        for digit in item.strip(): 
            lst.append(int(digit)) # append digits in to the list and convert them to int

print(lst)
[7, 3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6, 2, 4, 9, 1, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('txtfile', 'r') as f:
    x = f.read()
print [y for y in list(x) if y != '\n']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete solution:

```
num = '''7316717653
      1330624919'''
num = num.replace('\n', '')
# Write to a text file:
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(num)

# Now write to a Python List:
fd = open('filename.txt','rU')
chars = []
for line in fd:
    chars.extend(line)
```

> Output is: **[7, 3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6, 2, 4, 9, 1, 9]**